# fail to update database with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a question and i hope somebody can help me.
I am using jquery dropable. What i wanna do is when i change the position of an element, i want to write the index into my database based on this example:
http://linssen.me/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/

Everything works fine but when i want to write into my database i'm getting an error.

This is wat my html and jquery looks like:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
    #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test-list").sortable({
            handle : '.handle',
            update : function () {
                var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
                $("#info").load("process-sortable.php?"+order);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<div id="info">Waiting for update</div>
</pre>
<ul id="test-list">
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('12105');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM buitenladder1 WHERE parent =37';
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($name_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <li id="listItem_<?echo $name_row['id']?>">
        <img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16"     class="handle" />
        <strong>Item 1 </strong>with a link to <a href="http://www.google.co.uk/" rel="nofollow">Google</a>
    </li>
<?}?>
</ul>
<form action="process-sortable.php" method="post" name="sortables">
<input type="hidden" name="test-log" id="test-log" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The sortable functions loads this php script:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "12105";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

foreach ($_GET['listItem'] as $position => $item)
{
$sql[] = "UPDATE `buitenladder1` SET `b_index` = $position WHERE `id` =$item";
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
/* echo "New record created successfully";*/
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

If i write $sql without the '[]' then it works but it only writes one element in my database. When i use the '[]' i'm getting: 'Error Array'

Hope somebody can help me i'm pretty new to ajax and mysql.